# Three.js Hide Center Transform Controls

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to hide the central controls of the three.js transform controls and only show the xyz arrows in the controller. I've marked via a red circle the portions of the controller I'm trying to hide in the attached image.

[image]

I found in the documentation that you can hide the various axis like this.
https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/TransformControls.showX:

```
control.showX = false
control.showY = false
control.showZ = false
```

But this hides the entire axis and I only want to remove the the central part of the controls and keep the axis arrows. I've searched on Google quite a bit but haven't found anyone with a similar requirement.

Does anyone know how to hide the area I've marked in red?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the center controls by running following code:

```
const gizmo = control._gizmo.gizmo;

 ['XYZ', 'XY', 'YZ', 'XZ'].forEach(axis => {
   const obj = gizmo.translate.getObjectByName(axis);
   obj.visible = false;
   obj.layers.disable(0);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this capability is built into the tool, but you can simply copy & paste the `.js` file into your app and make modifications to it. For example [the XY, YZ, XZ controls are declared in line 886](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/c94947ac1df0485f20d5d8d99b40c08a79a4e889/examples/jsm/controls/TransformControls.js#L886), so you could comment them out so they don't get built.

You'd also need to update the `import` statement at the top of the `TransformControls` file, so it's simply

```
import { ... } from 'three';
```

Instead of this looong one

```
import { ... } from '../../../build/three.module.js';
```