# How do I leave only the arrows in TransformControls mode translate?

Tags: javascript, three.js

At the moment `TransformControls` fits my needs but they have extra stuff like arrows in distance of the object and some squares. Is there anyway of me turning these off and instead keep only the arrows?
[image]

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { TransformControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/TransformControls.js';

const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
const theeBoxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00FF00 });
const theeBox = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, theeBoxMaterial);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    45,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    1000
);

const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(30);
scene.add(gridHelper);

scene.add(theeBox);

const orbitControls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
const transformControls = new TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
transformControls.attach(theeBox);
transformControls.setMode('translate')
scene.add(transformControls);

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

camera.position.set(50, 30, 20);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

const rayCaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
const mousePos = new THREE.Vector2();

let isDragging = false;

transformControls.addEventListener('dragging-changed', function (event) {
    orbitControls.enabled = !event.value;
    isDragging = event.value;
});



function animateTheeBox() {
    if (!isDragging && !orbitControls.enabled) {
        rayCaster.setFromCamera(mousePos, camera);
        const intersect = rayCaster.intersectObjects([theeBox]);

        if (intersect.length === 0) {
            const moveSpeed = 0.1;
            camera.position.x += (mousePos.x - 0.5) * moveSpeed;
            camera.position.y += (mousePos.y - 0.5) * moveSpeed;
            camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(animateTheeBox);
```

EDIT: Added image for reference

[image]

Minimal Reproducing Code. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Gizmo's class (*line #781*),

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/controls/TransformControls.js

```
class TransformControlsGizmo extends Object3D
```

and try according that, disable stuff

```
this.gizmo['translate'].XY.visible = false;
this.gizmo['translate'].YZ.visible = false;
this.gizmo['translate'].XZ.visible = false;
this.gizmo['rotate'].E.visible = false;
this.gizmo['scale'].XYZ.visible = false;
this.gizmo['scale'].XY.visible = false;
this.gizmo['scale'].YZ.visible = false;
this.gizmo['scale'].XZ.visible = false;
```

Update
according to this answer:
[Three.js Hide Center Transform Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68652311/three-js-hide-center-transform-controls)

```
const gizmo = transformControls._gizmo.gizmo;

["XYZ", "XY", "YZ", "XZ"].forEach((axis) => {
  const obj = gizmo.translate.getObjectByName(axis);
  obj.visible = false;
  obj.layers.disable(0);
});
```

Comment: `transformControls._gizmo.gizmo['translate'].XY` gives back `undefined`